# Spring 3 View Resolver return multiple views

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, view, apache-tiles

In my Spring 3 MVC application, I am overriding Spring's `ViewResolver` and overriding `resolveViewName` to add certain prefix like '**desktop**'

Apache Tiles 3 definition :

```
<definition name="desktop/person/account" extends="layout">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/desktop/person/account.view />
</definition>
```

Now, I have some requirements to support different versions for a 'desktop'
For instance request can come with a v1, v1.0 , v1.1.1, v2 etc versions.

So if there is any customization needed for a client v1.1.1, i can add one more definition in Tiles

```
<definition name="desktop/1.1.1/person/account" extends="layout">
    <put-attribute name="content" value="/WEB-INF/views/desktop/1.1.1/person/account.view />
</definition>
```

But now the problem is if a client request comes for v2, I want the view resolver to first look for the most matching ie. 2 , if that does not exist then fall back to most matching, which is this case is `desktop/1.1.1/person/account`

If there is request for 1.0.9, then since it doesn't exist then fallback to `desktop/person/account`